# Medical insurance cost prediction using Linear regression

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am a beginner to machine learning. I have some basic knowledge about linear regression and logistic regression.

As an initial step to apply the concepts that I have learnt so far in linear regression I have tried predicting medical insurance cost based on the features given in the dataset . I used the multiple regression for prediction.I have a accuracy score of 0.79 yet I am not satisfied with my model and I wonder whether this kind of coding will really help me to become a pro in Machine learning.

I would really like to know the approach to learn theoritical and coding concepts ML to become a pro in it.I would also like to really bring into notice that I am currently taking the Machine learning course taught by Andrew Ng in coursera platform.

I also need to know how to visualize Multiple regression.

This is [github](https://github.com/keerthanakumaran017/Machine_Learning/tree/main/Medical%20insurance%20cost%20prediction) link to the folder.

It contains the dataset and python code.

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('insurance.csv')
#matrix of X features
X=df.iloc[:,:-1].values
#vector of prediction values
y=df.iloc[:,-1].values
from sklearn.model_selection  import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
X_train[:,:]=sc.fit_transform(X_train[:,:])
X_test[:,:]=sc.fit_transform(X_test[:,:])

y_train=y_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_test=y_test.reshape(-1,1)

#y_train[:]=sc.fit_transform(y_train[:])
#y_test[:]=sc.fit_transform(y_test[:])

from sklearn.linear_model import  LinearRegression
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)



y_pred=reg.predict(X_test)
y_pred=y_pred.reshape(-1,1)
print(reg.score(X_test,y_test))
print("reg coefficents:")
print(reg.coef_)
print(reg.intercept_)
```

My dataset includes following columns:

```
age: age of primary beneficiary

sex: insurance contractor gender, female, male

bmi: Body mass index, providing an understanding of body, weights that are relatively high or low relative to height,
objective index of body weight (kg / m ^ 2) using the ratio of height to weight, ideally 18.5 to 24.9

children: Number of children covered by health insurance / Number of dependents

smoker: Smoking

region: the beneficiary residential area in the US, northeast, southeast, southwest, northwest.

charges: Individual medical costs billed by health insurance
```

Link to the dataset(kaggle):  https://www.kaggle.com/mirichoi0218/insurance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "*if it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to [...] then do so - but **also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time*" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: I will update the post.Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you doing that well. But instead of using random (for splitting data), you can use common ratio to split train & test set. Usually it is 80:20, 75:25 (train:test).

And if you using the basic split like train test split, you can only get one result. next time try to learn k-Fold cross validation to slitting the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggesstions  and I will try out the K-fold cross validation approach.